# nmap can only scan specific host

Tags: nmap

Nmap keeps telling me no hosts are up when I am using scanning with an IP range
Ive tried using `sudo` and `192.168.0.1/16` and the same results shows

```
ermine-c@ubuntu:~/Desktop$ nmap -sn 192.168.1.1-255
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2021-03-17 00:34 PDT
Nmap done: 255 IP addresses (0 hosts up) scanned in 103.19 seconds
```

However when I am trying to scan for a specific host in my LAN network, nmap tells the host is up

```
ermine-c@ubuntu:~/Desktop$ nmap -sn 192.168.0.103
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2021-03-17 00:46 PDT
Nmap scan report for 192.168.0.103
Host is up (0.021s latency).
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.04 seconds
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Are you locating at behind the firewall?

Comment: You are using different networks: 192.168.1.0 for the network scan, and 192.168.0.0 for the host scan.

Comment: You need to describe the network and how things are set up. And this is not looking like a security question at all. That, and your two scans are targeting different subnets ...